# Can I run tasks on a specific event in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to run a task (or a macro from [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EXCEEDSYSTEM.vscode-macros) extension) when a specific event inside VS code is fired. More specifically, I want my tasks to run when debugging is finished i.e. on the onDidTerminateDebugSession event as listed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api).

At first, I considered writing an extension for this, but I'm sure the time will come when I simply want to run a different task on a different event.

Is this possible without writing an extension for each time I require this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open VSCode,
2. type `Ctrl + Shift + p`
3. type Tasks
4. select Configure Task
5. Select Create tasks.json file from template
6. Select Others
7. Enter your custom logic

[Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks)

Comment: reference https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How can I make this task run on a specific event e.g. when debugging begins?